# Can't get cookies from server side (golang) in a react app (CORS)

Tags: reactjs, go, cookies

I have a quite simple server application written in go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
)

type Message struct {
    Text string `json:"text"`
}

var cookieQuotes = []string{
    ...
}

const COOKIE_NAME = "your_cookie"

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/set_cookie", setCookie)
    mux.HandleFunc("/get_cookie", getCookie)
    mux.Handle("/favicon.ico", http.NotFoundHandler())
    handler := cors.Default().Handler(mux)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler)
}

...
```

Well, I have skipped the most of code here, but let me explain what it does.

When we go to /set_cookie path, we are getting a cookie to our browser. Cookie has a Value, which is encrypted text of quote about a cookie. So, here is the function:

```
func setCookie(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    quote := getRandomCookieQuote()
    encQuote := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(quote))
    http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
        Name: COOKIE_NAME,
        Value: encQuote,
    })
}
```

This app is deployed in VirtualBox in a docker container.

So, when I'm accessing the

> http://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/set_cookie

the cookie is set to the browser. And when I access

> http://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/get_cookie

I get decrypted text from a cookie (but this doesn't matter in case of this question)

The client side is written in React. Well, I think it is not necessary to post all the code of the application, but the main part is here:

```
export const setCookie = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get(URL+SET_COOKIE_PATH);
  console.log('set_cookie', res);
};
```

It is the the same thing as if we just called

> http://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/set_cookie

But I can't get the cookie to the browser. Never. I get the response with status code 200 and everything seems to be okay, but I don't get a cookie.

I have to mention, that this is a cross site thing.

So, the question is: How could I pass cookie from server to client?

Comment: You "pass cookie from server to client" via a Set-Cookie header (constructed by `http.SetCookie`). This seems fine. Note that the browser need not accept the cookie. Some of these rejections are controlled by user settings like rejecting third party cookies (which everybody should reject). If your React-triggered request is not considered an original request then the browser might discard the received cookie as third-party. You should not rely on being able to set (or even read) cookies cross site.

Comment: But is this possible to make a non-cross-site application with golang server and react client? And if not, what are the alternatives to hold user's data in browser?

Comment: Modern browser offer much more than cookies: Local/Session storage, Indexeddb and Web SQL.

Comment: Is JWT a good idea to start with?

Comment: JWT is something different so I do not understand how it could solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to write proxy variable in `package.json` to get of CORS

For example, if client is on `localhost:3000` and server is on `localhost:8080`, we should add:

> "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"

And access any path of server API with domain of client side, like:

> http://localhost:3000/set_coookie